# Why does cpu usage never reach 100%?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I have a dual-core processor. I'm running two instances of the program below:

```
void main(){
    int i;
    while(1){
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

I run TOP and CPU usage gets up to 97%, however it never reaches 100%, why doesn't it? CPU is supposed to be always busy running the two programs with no I/O operation.

Thank you

Comment: It has to do with the OS is time slicing, and may reserve a small potion to accept interupts.  Different priorities, different cpus (multi-core?), and even compiler flags can have an affect.

Comment: if CPU usage reached 100%, would the system crash?

Comment: I'm slightly surprised the compiler didn't optimize away all the code. The code is functionally identical to `void main(){}` isn't it? I would expect maxint to be reached almost instantly, presumably integer overflow is not regarded as noteworthy by your C compiler.

Comment: @ostri: No. operating systems have higher priority than apps and (on modern mass-market CPUs) run in a privileged CPU state that gives them control over runaway apps (in theory anyway).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Think your comment/question would be more interesting for the SO.  And isn't integer overflow more to do with CPU instructions?  Think MMX

Comment: @hydroparadise: Mea culpa. [But](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7776/Arithmetic-Overflow-Checking-using-checked-uncheck)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, do you mean that the CPU usage shown by TOP command is not actually the true CPU usage? Is there a percentage of the CPU reserved only for the SO that is not shown there? Are there processes of the SO that are not shown there?

Comment: @hydroparadise, what do you mean by "integer overflow has more to do with CPU instructions? could you explain it to me?

Comment: @ostri I think RedGrittyBrick corrected me in that it still *can* be a function of the compiler in his `But` link.  AFA cpu usage particularities in linux, this might be a better question for unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: What do you mean by "BUT link"? Im sorry, I still don't understand whether an int overflow occurred or not and what has the compiler to do with that.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7776/Arithmetic-Overflow-Checking-using-checked-uncheck.